# How to show a confirm message before leaving page? (Oracle Apex 21.1.0)

Tags: oracle-apex

My application has a page called P13_SHOP_DETAIL.

I want to show a Confirm Message before leaving the page. It shows when clicking on the `Desktop Navigation Menu` and leaving the page. And it causes only this page.

If possible, set the timing to show the message `click a back button on browser` and `click the Desktop Navigation Menu`

How can I do this?

Thank you for all the people to look at this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the existing feature of the page:
set the Warn on Unsaved Changes to checked.

[page properties > navigation > Warn on Unsaved Changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5osHn.png)

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! It worked exactly how I hoped it would.
That answer makes me happy :D

Comment: Thank you! It solved now!!!
I made a mistake. where to set the success message.